# Как сделать фигуру: окружность с выпуклостью в виде треугольника?

Tags: css

Как добиться такого эффекта создания треугольника из окружности, используя только  *CSS*?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#test:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 38px;
  top: -11px;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

пипка - это квадрат, у которого два бордера, повёрнут на 45 градусов и фон совпадает с фоном круга. Остальное уже можно самому доделать

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```